# Accept access request - get only permissions to choose from

Tags: permissions

I want to assign users to permission groups but when I process the access request by going to '...' I get a drop-down field that has only permissions and not permission groups. I have created custom permission which I have assigned to a custom permissions group. Now I want that when users send me an access request I assign them directly to the custom permissions group. The list I am giving access to has a stop inheritance done on it. Custom permission groups were created before inheritance was severed and hence are available inside the list.

Answer (score 0):

The above behavior occurs if the inheritance is severed. Once unique permissions are revoked and list again starts inheriting permissions from it's parent site the option of assigning someone directly to a permission group(standards well as custom) starts apperaing when you click on '...' while processing the access request.